# Why do you need to subtract from size of array?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

When I try to run the second line without subtracting from the size of the array, it won't work. Why not?

```
values = [10, 9, 11, 2, 45]
max_element = values.size - 1
first = values[0]
for i in 0..max_element
  while first < values[i]
    first = values[i]
  end
end
p "The largest value is #{first}"
```

Besides methods on `Enumerable` or `Array` such as `each`, is `for` the only iterator that loops over a collection of elements?

Comment: What's the error message? Is it an array out of bounds issue?

Comment: If you tried to iterate from `1` like `1..values.size`, then it would simply be lack of knowledge; you didn't know that index is zero-based, which is a reasonable mistake. But that is not the case. You know that index starts with `0` and are still expecting `0..value.size` to work. I have no idea how you can think that to work.

Comment: @sawa, call it befuddlement. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because array indices are zero-based, just like in C or Java:

```
values = [10, 9, 11, 2, 45]
values.size #=> 5

values[0] #=> 10 (1st element)
values[4] #=> 45 (last element)
values[5] #=> nil (this is beyond the last item)
```

You can use [`...`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Ranges) (three dots) to exclude the range's end:

```
for i in 0...values.size
  # ...
end
```

Furthermore, your `while` should be an `if`:

```
if first < values[i]
  first = values[i]
end

# or

first = values[i] if first < values[i]
```

Comment: hey thanks. If you noticed my last sentence, I'm trying to avoid `each` and `max`, etc. Hence this "program."

Comment: @user27307254534534534543 didn't see that, I've updated my question.

Comment: I definitely appreciate your answer, especially the three dots thing to exclude the end. And thanks for pointing out that my `while` should have been an `if`.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543 BTW, I think you can skip the first element (because of `first = values[0]`) and start at `1`, i.e. `for i in 1...values.size`

Comment: thanks! (oy vey, bah humbug to the 15 characters in length required!)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays start their element count at index `0`. The `values.size` gives you the number of elements within the array (which starts with 1 for a non-empty array). Check the following examples:

```
values  = [10  , 9   ]
index   =  0     1
size    =  2

values  = [10  , 9   , 11  , 2   , 45   ]
index   =  0     1     2     3     4
size    =  5
```

That's why the last element is always at the `index` of `values.size - 1`

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Because it will take max_element = 5 (size of values) and when i get to 5, you access values[5] in the while loop which is out of the range of values array

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain the out of range in loop.